# Is there a complete conversation convergence app?

Tags: contacts, email, twitter, sms

I was very impressed when I saw the first demo of WebOS quite a while back. I loved the way they integrated SMS, email, and social media all into one stream. Their point was that the most useful view was one oriented around the people, not the media. I think that's a very good point.

I've heard that FriendStream on HTC is pretty good but I have a samsung device.

I'm a big fan of Tweetdeck which brings together four (currently) social networks. You can post to all four at the same time, for those soap box moments :-)

I'd like to see an app that brings together EVERYTHING! even the voicemail and call log!

Am I asking the impossible?

Comment: Asking for the "best" anything is a fairly subjective question. Better to be specific about your needs; whether they can be met is at least objective.

Comment: Fair point, likely to incite flames. Edited

Comment: Not flames so much as it's off-topic. From the FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Answer (score 1):

Many have tried.  It's arguable whether anyone succeeded yet or not.

The big ones are Motorola's MotoBLUR, HTC's SenseUI, Samsung's TouchWiz - they all try to bring together the disconnected social aspects of different applications such as e-mail, text messages, and various social networks.  Each does it differently, with varying degrees of success.  Unfortunately these aren't stand-alone products.  They usually come pre-installed with their respective manufacturers' devices, and overhaul more than just social aspects.

There are also 3rd-party apps and widgets that attempt to do this merge.  One of the best that I've used is [SlideScreen](http://slidescreenhome.com/). I didn't like the fact that it replaces your launcher, but it sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I have only used Slide Screen for a short bit (it's a good app, though not quite for me since I don't live the social media life), I'm quite sure there is an option to use SlideScreen as a standalone app (i.e. does not replace the home screen).

Comment: I might have used it way back when they didn't have that option.

Comment: The SlideScreen project is now defunct.